# Date input changes width on hover in Chrome 87 when using custom font

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to find a way around this Chrome bug that adjusts the size of a data input when it's hovered (internally the `::-webkit-datetime-edit` element):

```css
body {
  font-family: Fraunces, sans-serif;
}

input {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="date" />
```

Note that the date part `::-webkit-datetime-edit` gets wider on hover, how can I workaround the bug (preferably I don't have to trigger a reflow for this in JS)? I picked a random font here and it's still broken.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but giving the input a fixed width in your css seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks although I'm hoping not to do that as another browsers or touch devices could display it differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Chrome 90